# Ports used in aws boto connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, aws-security-group

I am using a Lambda function which uses boto library to perform actions over EMR such as describe-cluster. I would like to know which ports are being used to restrict outbound Lambda security group for this communication. I do not find this information in AWS documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All AWS endpoints are HTTPS.

See [AWS Regions and Endpoints - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#emr_region)